# PHP Friends List Variable

Tags: php

I have been working on a php "friend system", and I have recently constructed the friends list. Right now if a user has no friends it will just show a blank table, I want it to only show the table of friends if the user has friends, otherwise I just want it to say something like "You haven't added any friends yet". 
Here is the code, please excuse the sloppiness.

```
<table class="table">
<tr>
<th><h4>Username</h4></th>
<th><h4>Jam</h4></th>
<th><h4>Jam Artist</h4></th>
<th><h4>Youtube Link</h4></th>

</tr>
<?php
if(!empty($frnd_query)){
 echo "Bull";
}
    $my_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
    $frnd_query = mysql_query("SELECT user_one, user_two FROM frnds WHERE user_one='$my_id' OR user_two='$my_id'");
    while($run_frnd = mysql_fetch_array($frnd_query)){
        $user_one = $run_frnd['user_one'];
        $user_two = $run_frnd['user_two'];
        if($user_one == $my_id){
            $user = $user_two;
        } else {
            $user = $user_one;

        }
        $username = getuser($user, 'username'); 
        $Jam = getuser($user, 'JamTitle');
        $JamAuthor = getuser($user, 'JamAuthor');
        $link = getuser($user, 'YoutubeLink');
        $profile = getuser($user, 'profile');

if(!empty($JamAuthor)){         
     $JamAuthor = $JamAuthor;
} else{
 $JamAuthor = "Unknown";
}
if(!empty($Jam)){           
     $Jam = $Jam;
} else{
 $Jam = "No Current Jam";
}
if(!empty($profile)){           
     $profile = "<img src='images/profile/$profile' class='img-circle' width='20' height='20'>";
} else{
 $profile = '<img src="images/profile/default.jpg" class="img-circle" width="20" height="20">';
}
if(!empty($link)){          
     $link = "<a href='$link' target='_blank'>$Jam on Youtube</a>";
} else{
 $link = "No Youtube Link";
} ?>            


       <tr> 
 <td><b><?php echo "<a href='profile.php?user=$user' class='boxuser' style='display:block'>"; ?>
<?php echo $profile; ?> <?php echo $username; ?></a></b></td>
<td><?php echo $Jam ?></td>
<td><?php echo $JamAuthor ?></td>
<td><?php echo $link; ?></td>
       </tr>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: $frnd_query in line 10 are always empty variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `mysql_num_rows` to check record. your codes is messy, try this :

```
<?php
$my_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
$frnd_query = mysql_query("SELECT user_one, user_two FROM frnds WHERE user_one='$my_id' OR user_two='$my_id'");

// check record in db existence
if(!mysql_num_rows($frnd_query)){
    echo "You haven't added any friends yet";
}
else{   
     while($run_frnd = mysql_fetch_array($frnd_query)){
        $user_one = $run_frnd['user_one'];
        $user_two = $run_frnd['user_two'];
        if($user_one == $my_id){
            $user = $user_two;
        } else {
            $user = $user_one;

        }
        $username = getuser($user, 'username'); 
        $Jam = getuser($user, 'JamTitle');
        $JamAuthor = getuser($user, 'JamAuthor');
        $link = getuser($user, 'YoutubeLink');
        $profile = getuser($user, 'profile');

        if(!empty($JamAuthor)){         
             $JamAuthor = $JamAuthor;
        } else{
         $JamAuthor = "Unknown";
        }
        if(!empty($Jam)){           
             $Jam = $Jam;
        } else{
         $Jam = "No Current Jam";
        }
        if(!empty($profile)){           
             $profile = "<img src='images/profile/$profile' class='img-circle' width='20' height='20'>";
        } else{
         $profile = '<img src="images/profile/default.jpg" class="img-circle" width="20" height="20">';
        }
        if(!empty($link)){          
             $link = "<a href='$link' target='_blank'>$Jam on Youtube</a>";
        } else{
         $link = "No Youtube Link";
        } 

        $rows .= " 
        <tr> 
            <td><b><a href='profile.php?user=$user' class='boxuser' style='display:block'>$profile $username</a></b></td>
            <td>$Jam</td>
            <td>$JamAuthor</td>
            <td>$link</td>
        </tr>
        ";
     }
     print $table = "
        <table class='table'>
            <tr>
                <th><h4>Username</h4></th>
                <th><h4>Jam</h4></th>
                <th><h4>Jam Artist</h4></th>
                <th><h4>Youtube Link</h4></th>
            </tr>
            $rows
        </table>
    ";
}
?>
```

no error checking and no tested yet, this is just my idea. Hope it helps! :)

Comment: I replaced my code with yours and besides sorting out a couple of things it worked great! thanks for all the help.

Comment: You are welcome. Another advise for you, write coding using PHP as base environment and avoid using too much <?php ... ?>. :)